# Create custom Stripe checkout confirmation page

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to show a dynamic link on the confirmation page of the checkout of Stripe, is it possibile to edit the checkout confirmation page code ?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout doesn't have a "confirmation page code". Instead, when you use Checkout you create a `Session` via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create) and you pass the `success_url` and `cancel_url` parameters to indicate where Checkout should redirect the customer after a successful payment or a cancelation.

In both cases, you would redirect the customer to your own website/app/page where you fully control the code and can customize it to your liking. This is covered in Stripe's documentation in details: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page